# A trip to the library

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, story

> I try to go to the library at least once every month, so I've developed a pretty good relationship with the librarian, a nice old man who sometimes teases me about my broad set of interests. Yesterday, for example, I brought him the following books to borrow:
>
> - *The Book of Bourbon: How to Brew Your Own Whiskey*, by Moses C. Kerne
> - *Gramática de la Lengua Española*, by Lucas E. La Fe
> - *Secrets of Freemasonry*, by Dave Orsini
> - *Rhine Stones: Sculpture in the Carolingian Empire*, by Alden R. Roofs
> - *Not Playing Fair: Non-Euclidean Geometries*, by Vera Allcub
>
> He looked at the books quizzically and smiled at me:
>
> "You know what?", he said, "I have one right here that I think you'll love. Take it home". He reached for it. Its name was *Life in the Weimar Republic: 20 Essays*, by Gerr Hinder. I was unconvinced, but he insisted. "One more book won't hurt!"
>
> I sighed and added the book to the pile. The librarian started laughing as I handed him the library card, and mysteriously said: "That was a good game, if a bit short. Maybe you'll win next time."

**What was the librarian talking about?**

Edit: I removed the pattern tag (I thought about it and it doesn't really fit) and replaced it with a cipher one, which should help.

---

**Hint 1**

> I came back to the library, and was greeted enthusiastically by the librarian. I still hadn't finished the six books I took home, but a couple of subjects had piqued my interest in the meantime.
>
> "Hey!, I said, "Can you recommend me anything to read about Zoroastrianism? Or  Kantian epistemology?"
>
> "Lots of stuff", he replied. "But, after our little exchange last time, I'm afraid those are off-limits".
>
> "What do you mean? Did I do something wrong?", I asked, a little scared.
>
> "Oh, no, not really. But if you want to play again, you'll have to pick something from the Technology aisles".
>
> I didn't want to make an enemy of the librarian, so I decided to humor him. I chose *The 100 Most Useless Patents Filed in the U.S.*, since it seemed to be an easy read. But when the librarian saw it he sighed and said, "oh, not *that* one".

**Hint 2 (not much of a hint, really)**

> The puzzle is almost solved, with only the *deciphering* (actually *decoding* if that helps) part remaining. Once that's done, the game that's taking place should be obvious. Think about why a Technology book is required to start the game anew.

**Hint 3 (some story)**

> I spent much of the week trying to find out how to play the game the librarian was referring too. I had an idea of what game it was supposed to be, but how the books could contain the information to play it was still a mystery. I came back to the library and leaned towards the old man's desk, whispering. "So... *794*, right?"
>  The man laughed and replied, "Right. But I don't know if reading any of those would help". He saw the look of confusion on my face, so he added: "Different rules, you fool!".
>  "How so?", I asked.
>  "To begin with, last time we didn't really play, I just made one last move. Half a move, actually, didn't have much of a choice."
>  "Look, I don't even know how to make moves. So maybe let's start with that."
>  "Oh, you should head out to the 00x then, mate!. The table should be in some book there. Then when you're ready to start, bring me two books. Then I'll give you two back and so on."
>  "First one should be a Technology one, right?". 
>  "Or something about the Greek language if you're feeling adventurous...". He scratched his head, like he had forgotten something. "Right, I didn't tell you about the name changes. That one should be obvious enough, and you won't need the other one anytime soon. I hope so, anyway. Good luck!"

About this hint: most parts about the "gameplay" aren't important to solve the puzzle, they're just there to make it a little bit more consistent (and probably more confusing, too). Just focus on:

> where you could find the decoding system inside the library, and maybe the 1 book = half a move part.

Comment: "Not Playing Fair" is a great title for a book on Non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: When I thought those were real books and googled them...

Comment: rot13(nantenz bs Tree Uvaqre vf erq ureevat...)

Comment: @ome also the others'

Comment: Not sure if this is coincidence, but there seems to be a "cipher" associated with each of the titles: [Glenlivet Cipher Whisky](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/the-glenlivet/the-glenlivet-cipher-whisky/), [Cipher of Gramatica](http://www.gutenberg-e.org/kirkbride/detail/romberch_gramatica.html), [Freemason's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher), [Rijndael (pronounced **Rhine**-doll)](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Rijndael), [Playfair cipher](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php), [Weimar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Weather_Cipher)

Comment: (admittedly, some of them are a stretch, but the Freemason's and Playfair jumped out at me right away)

Comment: Another candidate for the Weimar cipher: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a326/2706217f8a3addc15eb952ac0c9f2c20973d.pdf

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It absolutely is a coincidence, but dang, that's eerie

Comment: Hey there, any hints??

Comment: How important is the order of the books given?

Comment: @DqwertyC It is very important.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I considered adding it but the description says it's for puzzles where you must determine the winner of a game, which isn't really the case here I suppose.

Comment: @NudgeNudge how much longer to appeal for another hint? :D

Comment: @bhooks You are very very very close, so probably a couple of days? I'll have to think of what clue should I give anyways

Comment: We don't feel very close xD

Comment: @Joe I see ;) The thing is, by far the hardest thing has already been solved, and it's only a couple steps from there to the solution. And they're your typical, everyday Puzzling SE steps, so I'm not sure if I can give any "mysterious" hint for them.

Comment: Is this some sort of "game" where there are no turns, or one "player" can make 5 "moves" where only 1 response move is needed to win?

Comment: @bhooks That's a good question. The game wasn't played how it's supposed to be played, so the librarian only won in the sense that the narrator couldn't continue playing that game. It should be easier to solve the cipher than to guess the game though, even if it's a very very popular game.

Comment: I dunno, I personally felt that the Dewey part was the easiest bit (first thing I thought of, before it was posted on here) but still can't figure out a way to decipher the numbers. I've even tried rot13(genafcbfvat gur ahzoref vagb n fhqbxh tevq) but that doesn't make sense. You may be mis-judging the difficulty of deciphering, as I can't see any clues as to how we should be trying to decipher it (like the title was a clue to using the Dewey system)

Comment: @Joe You may be right I could have misjudged it, considering I obviously know what the answer is. It's definitely not something as convoluted as what you tried. I'll add a couple of clues to see if that makes it any easier.

Comment: @NudgeNudge Finally figured it out! Please check my updated response

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update: Figured it out! They are playing:

> Chess. The Dewey Decimal Codes put together in pairs of two represent chess moves when converted from Hexadecimal to Characters
>
>  66+34 = f4
>  65+36 = e6
>  67+34 = g4
>  51+68+34 = Qh4
>
>  The first three moves (plus the optional 4th by the Librarian) represent [Bird's Opening](https://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=4&n=1214&ms=f4.e6.g4)

Explanation of Hints

> Technology Book: You need to start with a technology book as the possible opening moves are for the pawns which are denoted by small letters a-h, which are Hex values 61-68 (or 61x to 68x in Dewey Decimal for this puzzle)

Here's my initial thoughts if it helps kick this off:

> It could be related to the Dewey Decimal System
>  The books in order would correspond to these codes
>
>  **663** Beverage Technology $\rightarrow$ The Book of Bourbon: How to Brew Your Own Whiskey
>  **465** Grammar of standard Spanish $\rightarrow$ Gramática de la Lengua Española
>  **366** Secret associations & societies $\rightarrow$ Secrets of Freemasonry
>  **734** Sculpture from ca. 500 to 1399 $\rightarrow$ Rhine Stones: Sculpture in the Carolingian Empire
>  **516** Geometry $\rightarrow$ Not Playing Fair: Non-Euclidean Geometries
>
>  Librarian's Response:
>  **834** German essays $\rightarrow$ Life in the Weimar Republic: 20 Essays
>
>  Hint 1
>  **295** Zoroastrianism $\rightarrow$ Zoroastrianism
>  **121** Epistemology (Theory of Knowledge) $\rightarrow$ Kantian epistemology
>  **608** Patents $\rightarrow$ The 100 Most Useless Patents Filed in the U.S.

Comment: I don't want to say too much, but this is a big step in the right direction. Good job!

Comment: I suspect 366 not 209 and 734 not 733; and I think 943 not 834 (but could be wrong about that). And my guess is that the problem with 608 is the zero in the middle.

Comment: (None of this guessing makes the next step obvious to me, though the _kind_ of thing we're looking for seems clear enough.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan those were my thoughts when posting, just hoping to give someone more clever than I a kickstart!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Your first two corrections are right, as well as your last guess... The rest of codes are correct except the first one (there's a better fit). Then it's a matter of finding how that cipher tag comes into play (the hint should help with that)

Comment: Implemented the first two corrections, and updated the first code. Did not change 834 to 943

Comment: Also updated the formatting and added more possibilities based off Hint 1

Comment: Good job! Those are the correct codes

Comment: Yayyy, you got it. You can explain some of the hints if you want although they're obvious now (why you are forced to open with a Technology book, or what the name change is). Anyways, you get the check, congrats!

Comment: @NudgeNudge I understand the need for a Technology book, unsure about the name change right now

Answer (score 17):

I assume there is something more to this, but the authors' names can all be

> anagrammed to various synonyms of *red herring*:
>
>  1. *Moses C. Kerne* $\rightarrow$ **SMOKESCREEN**
>  2. *Lucas E. La Fe* $\rightarrow$ **A FALSE CLUE**
>  3. *Dave Orsini* $\rightarrow$ **A DIVERSION**
>  4. *Alden R. Roofs* $\rightarrow$ **FOOL'S ERRAND**
>  5. *Vera Allcub* $\rightarrow$ **A CURVEBALL**
>
>  And, of course, *Gerr Hinder* $\rightarrow$ **RED HERRING**

Comment: You are correct by all accounts, because there is something more to it. This just means rot13(gur anzrf bs gur nhgubef ner veeryrinag)

Comment: @NudgeNudge Yeah, that's what I figured...  I thought I'd post this since I went to the trouble of figuring it out, and to prevent others from wasting their time going down the same road...

Comment: um... dont want to be that person, but this *technically* isn't an answer, but only states some red herrings of the puzzle. of course i appreciate your effort (+1), but then it would be even better if you had commented it instead or wait for some more "real" progress before you post this as an answer. sorry if i am not entitled to say that, but just a friendly reminder. thanks mod!

Comment: I hear your concern. I feel like this is a legitimate "partial answer", as it explores and eliminates one particular potential solution path. But I'm open to other opinions. If others feel it should be deleted, I'm down with that.

Comment: As far as I can see, this doesn't add anything to OmegaKrypton's and msh210's observations, which were posted to the question as comments (the proper way to post non-answers) more than an hour earlier.

Comment: @Bass Fair enough.  I didn't see either of their comments until after I had posted my answer.  But it's true that they did point this out before I did.

Comment: It does add one thing, namely finding all the anagrams and thereby assuring us that _all_ the author names are likely irrelevant. Otherwise it could have turned out, e.g., that what we're trying to do is to find books whose titles match up somehow with all of a set of things associated with _one_ author's name. Not very likely, but not impossible. And having spent a few minutes anagramming names and not having found all of them, I'm grateful for having that line of attack definitively closed down.

Comment: (I do think comments would have been a better place than an answer, though.)